# knockout, how to subscribe child viewModel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

I am new to Knockout.  I have 2 ViewModels

First one has 2 address, home and mailing.

```
var EntityViewModel = function (clientId, taxYear) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(null);

    self.name = ko.observable('').extend({
        required: { message: ' Name is required' },
        validation: { validator: maxLength, message: ' Name must be less than 65 characters', params: 65 }
    });
    self.homeAddress = new AddressViewModel();
    self.mailingAddress = new AddressViewModel();
};
```

2nd one is the address view Model.  What I try to do is if state is -1, then country dropdownlist is enabled,  if state is > 0 , then country dropdownList is disabled, and the countryId is set to 1 which is united states. but the problem is everytime I change state, both home country and mailing country are enabled or disabled.  how do I fix it?

```
var AddressViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.address1 = ko.observable('');
    self.address2 = ko.observable('');
    self.city = ko.observable('');
    self.zipCode = ko.observable('');

    self.stateId = ko.observable(null);
    self.countryId = ko.observable(null);

    self.enableState = ko.observable(false);
    self.enableCountry = ko.observable(false);

    self.stateId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (newValue <= 0) {
            self.enableState(true);
            self.countryId(null);

        } else {
            self.enableCountry(false);
            self.countryId(1);
        }
    });
};
```

btw,I also has a different mailing address check box, if this checkbox is unchecked, then the whole mailing address is disabled. if the checkbox is checked, then you can edit.

I upload my code on jsFiddler,  please help me to fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/lm2000/2ZEka/22/

Answer (score 0):

Is this OK ?
http://jsfiddle.net/zUYGF/1/

Basically I just fixed your subscribe function, if I understood correctly what you want:

```
self.stateId = ko.observable(null);
self.countryId = ko.observable(null);
self.enableCountry = ko.observable(true);

self.stateId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue <= 0) {
        self.countryId(null);
        self.enableCountry(true);
    } else {
        self.countryId(1);
        self.enableCountry(false);
    }
});
```

I did it only for the first address. For the second one, you should use a named template rather than repeating code, I think (your AddressViewModel could have a global "enabled" attribute).